# $f'(x) \neq 0$ at a point in which f is minimum

Tags: derivatives, optimization

In theory we know that $f(x)$ is minimum or maximum when $f'(x) = 0$

Let's say $$f(x)=\frac{1}{x},x\in(0,1]$$

Then $$f'(x)=-\frac{1}{x^2}$$ where it is obvious that for $x \in (0,1]$ $f'(x)$ can not be zero. Although f is minimum for $x=1$.

How can this occurrence  be explained?

Comment: Your first line is not entirely true. If $f'(x)=0$ you do not have to have a max or min. Second part of your question. There is a min because you "chopped off" a great part of the function. By only considering a restricted domain you can "create" max or min depending on the curves behavior on that interval

Comment: The test you refer to goes completely different: **If** $f\colon(a,b)\to\mathbb R$ is differentiable **and** has a local extremum at an **interior** point $c\in(a,b)$, **then** $f'(c)=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it is not generally true that "$f(x)$ is minimum or maximum when $f′(x)=0$". Consider $f(x)=x^3$ for example.

Second, in an interval $[a,b]$, $f(x)$ can attain its minimum or maximum in three cases:
i) $f'(x)=0$;
ii) $f'(x)$ does not exist;
iii) the end point of the interval.
Hardly can we know which case it is before we examine them all.

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee that the derivative will exist. For example :

Take $$f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, f(x)=|x|$$

$f$ has a minimum at $0$ but $f$ is not even differentiable.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly , the first derivative test fails here.. As we can't get any critical points.

So , we use the interval we're given , so , $x \in (0,1]$ ,

Now f(x) would be minimum , when it's denominator is maximum..

Max. value of $x=1$ , thus , its minimum value is $1$.

I hope that helps !